# Access stdin file from At&t assembly

Tags: gcc, assembly, att

I am writing a program in at&t assembly which needs to get input from the user. I have been using `gets` for a while but am well aware of buffer overflow attacks. I wish to use `fgets` but am having trouble with how to go about giving it the stdin file.

```
push %rbp
mov  %rsp,        %rbp
sub  $0x20,       %rsp
lea  -0x20(%rbp), %rdi #Buffer
mov  $0x20,       %rsi #Size of buffer
mov  $0,          %rdx #Input stream?
call fgets
leave
ret
```

As shown above I tried just putting in 0 as it's the file descriptor for `stdin`. Is there any way I can get `stdin` without finding `stdio.h` and compiling my code with it every time like so...

```
gcc test.s stdio.h -o test
```

Any alternative solution is much appreciated.

Comment: `fgets` does not take a file descriptor, it takes a `FILE*`. Your code is wrong. You need to pass `stdin`. Note you don't need the header for that.

Comment: Which operating system are you programming for?

Comment: On some systems, `mov stdin, %rdx` works. It's worth a try. (Or `mov stdin(%rip), %rdx`.)